# jwplayer 6 with pre-roll video and xml file

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I'm trying with jwplayer 6 put an advertising video with a link for to close it in 10 seconds but I'm not an expert.

I've posted in the wowza forum but no answers, the url is this:

http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?35309-jwplayer-6-pre-roll-video-xml-file&p=133725#post133725[1](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?35309-jwplayer-6-pre-roll-video-xml-file&p=133725#post133725)

Can someone help me ??

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/35944/skipping-ads

```
<script>
  jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
    file: "/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
    primary: 'flash',
    advertising: {
      client: "vast",
     'skipoffset':10,   
      tag: "http://adserver.com/vastResponse.xml"
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan, but my probleme is not the code of jwplayer.

Comment: My proble is the vastResponse.xml, i have my wowza media server 3.5 and the advertising video is in content directory of wowza and the application is vod.

Comment: I need to made the xml similar to my playlist.php i use it with jwplayer 5.8

Comment: Can I see where you are running this?

Comment: 1) This url has a playlist for IOS and Flash with one video only and the playlist hiden. Is with jwplayer 5.8 and i can look it with android with flash plugin (firefox):

Comment: 2) This url has a playlist for IOS and Flash with 9 videos and the playlist is not hiden. Is with jwplayer 5.8 and i can look it with android with flash pludin (firefox):

Comment: With jwplayer 6 (i have the licence pro) is not possible to look the player flash with android with flash plugin (firefox) ??. Thanks for your atention Ethan.

Comment: You are using JW5 here on these links. That advertising set up is is for JW6. You need an ads license for JW6 in order to run ads.

Comment: i know the examples are with jwplayer5 and advertising is for jwplayer6. 
Excuse my English but i'm Spanish, I make an effort to understand. 
I repeat again, I need help to build the vastResponse.xml file, with the example of jwplayer5 only pretended to see if it is possible for vast, I see not. 
How can I build vastResponse.xml?